# How to make the return values of findOrCreate available to router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

So in my express app I have a separate file database.js, which contains all the models and functions for inserting, deleting, updating etc. I also have a separate controller for each model.

database.js

```
module.exports = {
    createUser: function (username, email, password) {
        return sequelize.sync().then(function () {
            User.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    username: name,
                    email: email
                },
                defaults: {
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    email: email
                }
            }).then(([user, created]) => {
                console.log(user.get({plain:true}));
                console.log(created)
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

controllers/user.js

```
const database = require("../database.js");
module.exports = {
    register: function (req, res) {
        database.createUser(req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password);
        res.json({...
        })

    }
};
```

So basically I wanna get the user object and the boolean that tells me if it was created to the router so I can check if the user was created and make an appropriate response.

Comment: Why do you even call `sequalize.sync()` in `createUser`? This is wrong. You shouldn't be calling it in app at all. You can unintenionally mess up your database (if you put somewhere `force: true` flag, then you are doomed), not to mention the sync overhead. The `sequalize.sync()` should run only during migrations.

Comment: Also Promises can chain return value: your final `.then` in `createUser` can simply `return [user, created];` to make it available in `user.js` via `.then()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove `then` in createUser and resolve the Promise when calling the function:

```
module.exports = {
    createUser: function (username, email, password) {
        return User.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    username: name,
                    email: email
                },
                defaults: {
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    email: email
                }
            })
    };
```

The promise will then resolve into an array with a user object and a boolean you're looking for

```
const database = require("../database.js");
module.exports = {
    register: function (req, res) {
        database.createUser(req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password)
            .then((result) => {
                const [ object, created ] = result;
                res.json({ user_is_created: created })
            })
    }
};
```

It's not a complete solution, you might have to explore edge cases and errors, but that's basically how you'd do it.